# Instagram Permission Denied for Public Content

Tags: permissions, instagram, instagram-api

Trying to get Instagram permission to get recent media that a user has liked. We applied for public_content permission but that has been denied with invalid use case as a reason. We have received the basic permission which lets us get a users recently posted media.

Our app / site is a community where users help each other find fashion products. Much like stackoverflow, a user asks a question with an image and the other members respond with answers as to where to buy them.

Thus getting a users 'liked' photos from instagram is vital in order to make asking the question much easier. The screencast we applied with is here: https://youtu.be/wr4HHyhD7jE

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For Instagram it is mean that you are violating copyright because You use photos by another people.